Get absolute hyperlink from excel via python script
I am using openpyxl to process information from a excel spreadsheet. The spreadsheet is in Microsoft sharepoint, when some hyperlink is added into it, if the hyperlink is in the same sharepoint, it will automatically been translated to relative URL when I click the "save" button.
If I copy this spreadsheet to some other PC location, the relative hyperlink simply cannot work. Microsoft provide a way to solve this in Help > Set the base address for the links in a workbook. But for openpyxl, it seems no method is provided to retrieve this base url address.
I don't want to hard code it in the python script because I need to process different excel sheets. Is there a way for the python script to translate the relative URL to absolute URL? Or alternatively, is there a way in excel itself to avoid storing the URL in relative form?
The code snippet to retrieve URL is as the following
wb = load_workbook(file, data_only=True)
sheet = wb[sheet_name]

# Extract the hyperlinks
hyperlinks = {}
for row in sheet.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        if cell.hyperlink:
            hyperlinks[cell.coordinate] = cell.hyperlink.target  # here the link might be relative


Have you tried to rebuild the absolute path by yourself ? from the path of the excel path, you could append relative links present in the spreadsheet. Also, could you provide some code you have tried in order to figure out how you access links with openpyxl ?

My code snippet is attached. The difficulty I meet is there is no way for openpyxl to read the base url

it will automatically been translated to relative URL when I click the "save" button how could Openpyxl read something that is not there?

@moken As I described, Microsoft provide a way to set "base url" in excel file. If that can be obtained from script there is way to rebuild the absolute link. But I don't find a way for openpyxl retrieve that

@EricSun, can't you just do something in the style of
hyperlinks[cell.coordinate] = file + cell.hyperlink.target
(maybe adjusting / for paths, or directly using os.path.join method) ? Is there something I'm missing ?

@Lrx, it is not local file system link, but Microsoft sharepoint URL. So os.path is not helping here

Look at the source of the file to see what Excel is actually doing as there is no such thing as "base URL" in OOXML.

Turn out after setting the base hyperlink, excel stops to convert URL to relative links. So this question can be closed.
